# why the format was different between API flask and pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, flask, flask-restful

so i have an output for pandas like this

```
print(data_science_part_2.RFMScores)
```

output:[image]

but why when i do this on flask to json

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
import data_science_part_2

@app.route("/")
def summary():
    out = data_science_part_2.RFMScores.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '} {')
    print(out)
    d = 'Hello World'
    return jsonify(out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

why the output becomes like this (column user didn't exists)

[image]

Comment: Seems like column `user` is a row index.  Do a reset_index() first ?

Comment: put ```reset_index``` in ```pandas``` or in ```flask```?

Comment: Do it on Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `user` is an index, not a column.

A simple approach would be copying `user` (i.e. the index) to a new column before converting to json.

```py
df['User'] = df.index
```